# streaming rtsp video in vlc plugin

Tags: javascript, video, rtsp

Hey I am tried to run rtsp video in the web, apparently it is not an easy task,
I have followed the documentation https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin
and add an embed script to my html with a valid target: `rtsp://122.248.252.56/live/nokia40mtv150.sdp`.

But apparently nothing happen, I don't see any controlers of the video player and don't see any video.
Any one has a clue why I can't run an rtsp video using vlc plugin?

I get a message in the chrome which tells that plugin isn't supported.
If this plugin isn't supported so how can I run rtsp video on the web.

**UPDATE:**
in IE, it is supported but it doesn't play the video

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
  width="100" height="100" target="rtsp://122.248.252.56/live/nokia40mtv150.sdp " />
```

Comment: update in IE, it is supported but it doesn't play the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome VLC Web Plugin doesn't work, in Firefox and IE it works ok.

Try next code, I verified it with another rtsp source, with yours `rtsp://122.248.252.56/live/nokia40mtv150.sdp` it doesn't work for me.

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" 
    codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab"
    style= "width: 200px; height: 200px;"
>
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://122.248.252.56/live/nokia40mtv150.sdp" />

    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
        width="200px"
        height="200px"
        src="rtsp://122.248.252.56/live/nokia40mtv150.sdp"
    />        
</object>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help and the quick respond, can you give me a valid rtsp source, I am looking for such source and didn't find any on the web. 
I need this resource for testing.

Comment: Try this: `rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4` get from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067817/sample-rtsp-url-for-video-streaming